# Pywinauto fails in VS Code and Succeeds in CMD

Tags: pywinauto

My very simple pywinauto code runs smoothly on VS code until recently.
In the last few days I didn't manage to run this code in VS code (always get an ElementNotFound exception) while the **exact same code** runs successfully in CMD.

Why is that?

**EDIT:**
Managed to overcome this - had to add wait() after application connect.

Comment: Could you please post your solution as an answer and accept it? Just to show others it's already answered. It's OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I have realized that adding sleep() interruptions after  Application.connect() resolved the abovementioned issue.